# Allowing Tablesorter filter widget filter_functions to target an external dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using version 2.20.1 of the forked version of the library and have the filter widget installed. We dont really want to use the inline filtering boxes so we have set `filter_columnFilters: false` and `filter_external: '.search'`. This is great because it allows our search box to be separate from the table.

We would also like to have a dropdown filter external to the table. I have two ideas how to implement this but need to be pointed in the right direction as I have yet to make either work.

First idea would be to use the built-in `filter_functions`:

```
filter_functions:
   {
      "#dateSelection": 
      {
         "30 Days": function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return ...; },
         "6 Months": function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return ...; },
         "All Time": function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return ...; }
      }
   }
```

However it appears that the jquery selector only targets `tr` tags within the table.

My second idea was to call a custom filter function. Something like `$("table").tablesorter.filter()` but I dont see any function to do manual filtering.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Is there a third option I havent thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter_function` selector needs to match the column header class.

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/36/), we set the header class to "english"

```
<th class="english">English</th>
```

Add an external select (include an option `value` attribute because IE won't work otherwise); a `data-column` attribute is also required.

```
English Scores: <select class="search" data-column="3">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="less-than-50">&lt; 50</option>
    <option value="between 50 & 90">50 to 90</option>
    <option value="greater than 90">&gt; 90</option>
</select>
```

Then set up the `filter_functions` to target the header class name, and include keys that match the option values:

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_columnFilters: false,
            filter_external: '.search',
            filter_functions : {
                '.english' : {
                    'less-than-50' : function(e, n) { return n < 50; },
                    'between 50 & 90' : function(e, n) { return n >= 50 && n <= 90; },
                    'greater than 90' : function(e, n) { return n > 90; }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are correct. I was misunderstanding the meaning of the filter_function key value. Also I was missing the search class on the select box. The sample was great for solving these issues.

Comment: Actually for built-in searches, you don't even need a `filter_functions` definition. So the above example can be reduced ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/37/)) - I left the `filter_functions` intact in this example in case you needed to make a more complicated comparison, one that isn't one of the [built-in filter search types](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom-search.html#builtin_filters).

Comment: Is it possible to make the second option the default?

Comment: Add `selected` to the option, then add a `data-value="second-option-value"` (the `data-value` attribute can be changed by the [`filter_dataAttrib` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-defaultattrib) - [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/38/)

Comment: I had a problem with the default in my scenario. I created an issue for it https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/831 since it is beyond this question. Thanks for the help here though!